# SlimScroll на 'live' элемент

Tags: jquery

Задача такова:
имеется таблица, которая генерируется jQuery через ajax. Собственно, не суть важно, как именно.

```
<div id="prod">
    <table>
        <tr><td>...<td></tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>

$("#prod").slimScroll({
        height: '500px'
    });
```

Если элемент див (prod) статический, то всё, понятное дело работает, как часы.
А вот если всё это дело было сгенерировано, то jQuery его не видит.
Как можно заставить работать сей код? )
Знаю, что повесить какой - то обработчик, типа Click, или что - то подобное, то можно воспользоваться методом live. А вот как повесить этот скролл, х3. )

Answer (score 1):

после генерации найди таблицу и повесь её обработчик, к примеру:

```
var table = $('<div id="prod"><table><tr><td><td></tr></table></div>');
table.slimScroll({
    height: '500px'
});
$("body").append(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Слушать ивент [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) и смотреть не сгенерировалась ли таблица, и вешать на нее slimScroll если сгенирировалась.